# ng-sidebar not working in nested module's component

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

My route for component with [ng-sidebar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-sidebar) is in not getting rendered at all. I've gone through the GitHub issues and applied `height:100%` property and I've also applied `position:static;` property, but that didn't help. My page gets loaded in the browser but it doesn't render at all (blank).

Point to mention here is that I'm using the `ng-sidebar-container` directive in a nested module's component. However I've also imported the `SidebarModule` in the nested module's import array and root module as well. Is the problem because I've used `SidebarModule.forRoot()` in the nested module or is it something else. Do I need to remove `.forRoot()`?

Comment: Woud it be possible for you to create a minimal [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) replicating this issue?

Comment: Got the same issue. I can't put the sidebar into its own component. It's not showing. Also, when I leave the `<ng-sidebar>` part inside of app.component.html and wrap it into a `div`, it doesn't show up. Seems that `<ng-sidebar>` needs to be an immediate child of `<ng-sidebar-container>`

Answer (score 0):

Request was added in v 7.2.0 by author (note that the package is no longer actively maintained) - [See pull request](https://github.com/arkon/ng-sidebar/pull/146)

**Solution**

You can now host your sidebar inside a child component so long as you add the `ng-sidebar` attribute to the component selector.

For example:
`<child-component-name ng-sidebar ></child-component>`